# I am using ionic3 and angular4 in mobile app, i have issue with ion-datetime my requirement is to show the current date and future 15 days only

Tags: ionic3

This is my HTML page where i used the ion-datetime

```
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Date of Admission</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime id="txtDOA" name="txtDOA" displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [min]="todayDate" [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="CashLessRequest.DOA"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
```

This is my ts page

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.todayDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
    this.CashLessRequest.DOA = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

**Screenshot**

[image: this is my how displaying presently datepicker on screen]

Comment: please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

you should use moment.js plugin to give maxDate for that you need to install

```
npm i moment
```

and then import it in your ts file

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

and then implement this code

HTML Page:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Date of Admission</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [min]="todayDate" [max]="maxDate" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

TS Page:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import * as moment from 'moment';

    @Component({
        selector: 'page-home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })


    export class HomePage {

        public date=moment().format();
        public todayDate=moment().format();
        public maxDate= moment().add(15,'d').format();

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

'max' is also a inbuilt parameter in ion-datetime directive so you can easily set the max limit value.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMMM YYYY" min="today" max="dateLimit" [(ngModel)]="myDate">
</ion-datetime>
```

In your .ts file

```
date: Date;
today : Date;
dateLimit : Date
//set min value using current date
this.today = new Date().toJSON().split('T')[0];

//set max date limit 
this.date = new Date();
this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate() + 15 );
this.dateLimit = this.date.toJSON().split('T')[0];
```

I hope the above code will help to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

this.min30days = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(Date.now() - 30*86400000) , "yyyy-MM-dd");